# Chromedriver is blocking camera. Works only in first window

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to run multiple Chrome windows, and in each I need to have camera working. Right now camera works only in first chrome window, and is blocked by this one in next windows. In second and next windows, even on webcamtests.com I have information that my camera is used in another application.

Everything works fine when I run Chrome manually. This issue appears only when I'm using webdriver (chromedriver)

I tried some chrome options like:

```
user-data-dir=/my_dir
disable-user-media-security
use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

I tried even `use-fake-device-for-media-stream` - and it worked, but I need real camera. This option gave me fake animation.

My code right now:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=/ChU/UDA30");
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
options.AddArguments("disable-user-media-security");
options.AddArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
options.AddArguments("always-authorize-plugins");
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driver_a30 = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

For every new window I have other user-data-dir. 
I would like to have camera in every window, not only in first one.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some walkaround - maybe someone have the same problem as me:

Chrome is blocking webcam for new chromedriver. 
So if I want to have webcam in many Chrome windows, I need to have only one chromedriver working at the same time.
So I'm running new Chrome windows on the same chromedriver, and then I have camera working everywhere.

Here's my code:

```
driver_chrome.SwitchTo().Window(driver_chrome.WindowHandles.First());
SendKeys.SendWait("^(n)");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
driver_chrome.SwitchTo().Window(driver_chrome.WindowHandles.Last()); 
driver_chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
```